# How to move a div up/down the dom on certain page width with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I'm fairly new to Jquery and this is a bit out of my league.

I want to move a div to a different location, which I can accomplish with:

```
$('#searchbar').insertAfter('.search-item');
```

Now what I want to do is write an if statement that says if the screen width is 800px do:

```
$('#searchbar').insertAfter('.search-item');
```

else(screen width above 800px) put it back to its original location.

I've tried searching but it seems pretty specific.

Any ideas or is there a better way to accomplish what I want?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: By screen width do you actually mean the resolution of the users screen? Or simply the width of the browser window or viewport?

Comment: @JamesHay Width of the browser/viewport. It's essentially being used for a mobile nav.

Comment: Did you consider just using [CSS media queries](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/)?

Comment: @Jonathan I'm modifying a wordpress theme and the search feature is a div that is not inside of the navigation because of the way it was designed (some fancy dropdown nonsense). On mobile I need it in the nav and to be able to interact with the the moving nav menu for sub items. I hope that made sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this with jQuery:

```
$(window).on("resize", function() { //or $(window).resize(function() {
    var w = $(this).width();
    if (w < 800) {
        //do less than action
    } else {
        //do else action
    }
});
```

As one commentor mentioned above, you might be able to do something like this using CSS.

Comment: This will work. I'm just not sure how to get the div back to it's original location.

Comment: Okay, I ended up just insertAfter'ing where it was originally so this seems to be working perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You can get the index of the item in its parent container before you move it, then use screen width to move it back.

Something like this

```
var searchbar = $('#searchbar');

// Get the parent container of the bar.
var parent = searchbar.parent();

// Get the starting location of the bar.
var index = parent.index(searchbar);

if($(window).width() >= 800){
    // Insert the bar after the '.search-item'
    searchbar.insertAfter('.search-item');
}
else{
    // Insert the bar in its original location
    $(parent.children()[index]).before(searchbar);
}
```